# How to match alphanumeric characters in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to match alphanumeric characters in my elasticsearch PHP client but it's not returning anything. This is the query:

```php
$this->client->search(
[
    'index' => 'partners',
    'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'regexp' => [
                'partner_id' => '.*23PR.*'
            ]

        ]
    
    ]
]
);
```

However the same query is working for text fields which contain purely text characters. For example:

```php
$this->client->search(
[
    'index' => 'partners',
    'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'regexp' => [
                'partner_name' => '.*adi.*'
            ]

        ]
    
    ]
]
);
```

Which is working fine.
What is the correct regex expression here?

**EDIT**

It is working when I use small letters in the query. For example: if I use regex in `partner_id` as `.*23pr.*`. It is matching fine. Is it wrong to use capital letters?

Comment: If you can add example test that match and unmatch I can help you better

Comment: Thanks @aditya. I answered to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try [case_insensitive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) option for regexp query.

An example:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "user.id": {
        "value": "k.*y",
        "flags": "ALL",
        "case_insensitive": true,  <------ this
        "max_determinized_states": 10000,
        "rewrite": "constant_score_blended"
      }
    }
  }
}
```